# SQL query to accdb with Parameters

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access, pyodbc

I have an Access database (DB.accdb) with one 'Table' which has a 'Date' column.
I would like to give the Date as a parameter and adapt the query as `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date > param_1 AND Date < param_2` , where `param_1` and `param_2` are predefined, but I struggle having the correct syntax. This is the code so far, does anyone have any suggestion?

```
conn_access = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=R:\DB.accdb;')
SQL_DAM = 'SELECT * FROM Table ;'
Query = pd.read_sql(SQL_DAM, conn_access, params=[])
```

Comment: like `SQL_DAM = f'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE date > {param_1} AND date < {param_2};'` ?

Comment: I tried this `start_date = '30/06/2020'` and `SQL_DAM = f'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE date = {start_date};'` . It didn't give any error, but it looped for a long time and returned an empty dataframe. I know there is data corresponding to this date in the db.

Comment: ah the issue is with quotes try `f"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE date = '{start_date}';"`

Comment: It looks better, but now I have this error: "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." I will probably need to make some conversions.

Comment: You can test it inside MSAccess it has a SQL editor

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it worked perfectly.